# Strange info boxes appears from time to time about 7zip or WinRar

Tags: conemu

I'm using ConEmu portable for win64 and from time to time this dialogs appears. Even when I working with other app. How to turn this off?

[image]

Comment: Install 7zip? Specify it's path in ConEmu settings?

Comment: Why should I install unnecessary programm to get rid of unnecessary dialog box?

Comment: Haven't you installed this program to unpack ConEmu distro?

Comment: Our discussion turned into a strange channel, may be I installed 7zip and then uninstalled it, may be I bring ConEmu unpacked because it's a portable version, may be I asked god to unpack ConEmu with his holy power... I just simply dont want to see this warning/error dialog without installing anything. Is this too much for such complex programm?

Comment: You have choices. If you want to autoupdate ConEmu, you have to install 7zip, or reinstall ConEmu via installer. Or you may disable auto update checks completely